# How to connect existing strapi server (without admin access to it) with React?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

As a recruitment task I have to create a React todo list with existing backend created with strapi (I've no experience working with strapi). I just got a link to documentation with urls like "/todo-lists" with specified methods GET, POST etc. and a link to the strapi server, page displays a following message "The server is running successfully (v0.1.0)" and a button that links to admin panel, but I can't access it. Is there a possibility to connect this server to React app just by url of the server? I'm looking for an answer in the documentation of strapi but I found only how to create a new server with admin access.

Comment: *"documentation with urls like "/todo-lists" with specified methods GET, POST etc. and a link to the strapi server"* - Have you made requests to those URLs on that server?  Did they fail in some way?  It sounds like you're trying to figure out how to manage the API you've been given, but the expectation seems like you just need to use the API as-is and focus on building your React app.

Comment: @David when I'm trying to use urls given in documentation I get an 403 error "Forbidden", but it may be just because I add for example "/todo-lists" after server url (if created locally it would look like localhost:1337/todo-lists)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you get 403 forbidden, like mentioned in the commets, it would be helpful to look at your API call implementation in the react app. Do you use axios, and have you added the bearer token?